# CodeIgniter - View page is not loading but function returns response on console

Tags: codeigniter, view, load

I am trying to handle the server response.I parse this response VIA ajax to my controller. From console , I get correctly the result from `POST getInternalRouteServerResponse` , but VIEW page is not loading. Any idea?

Here is my controller :

```
public function getInternalRouteServerResponse()
{
    $response = $this->input->post();

        $html = $this->load->view("front/curse_interne.php", array(
            'response' => $response
        ), true);
        echo json_encode(array("status" => 1, "html" => $html));
}
```

And this is my view (curse_interne.php):

```
<?php var_dump($response); exit();?>
```

Am I loading correctly my view?
Thank you in advance!

UPDATE: Added the ajax code here :

```
$.ajax({ //hande the first response
    url: MyVariable.urlsite + "curse_interne/searchInternalRoute",
    type: "POST",
    dataType: 'json',
    data:
    '&departure=' + $("#internal_origin_station option:selected").val()
    + '&arrival=' + $("#internal_destination_station option:selected").val()
    + '&date=' +  $("#datepicker_plecare").val()
    + '&category=' + categories
    + '&clear_session=1',

    beforeSend: function () {
        $('html, body').animate({scrollTop: $('#right-content-mainwrapper').position().top}, 'slow');
        $("#right-content-mainwrapper").html("<div style='font-size: 18px;margin-bottom: 25px;margin-top: 25px;text-align: center;'>Va rugam asteptati. Calculam rutele interne.</div> \n\
                    <div  style='text-align:center;'><img src='" + base_url + "assets/images/loader-big.gif' style='display: inline-block;vertical-align: middle;margin-left:10px;'/></div>\n\
         ");
    },
    success: function (response) {
        if (response.status == '1') {

            $.ajax({ // here is the response that I want to show in view
                url: MyVariable.urlsite + "curse_interne/getInternalRouteServerResponse",
                type: "POST",
                dataType: 'json',
                data: response

            })



        } else {
            $("#right-content-mainwrapper").html("<div id='right-content-mainwrapper'>\n\
                        <div id='comanda-bilet-maincontent'><div class='error'>" + response.message + "</div></div></div>");
        }
    }

})
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Need to some correction your second ajax call. You missed `success`. and add bellow line after success like

```
$("#right-content-mainwrapper").html(data.html);
```

So,

```
$.ajax({ // here is the response that I want to show in view
    url: MyVariable.urlsite + "curse_interne/getInternalRouteServerResponse",
    type: "POST",
    dataType: 'json',
    data: response,
    success: function (data) {
        //console.log(data.html);
        $("#right-content-mainwrapper").html(data.html);
    }
})
```

Comment: I did removed, but the same... Just aded ajax code, the secodn ajax send the response on my controller.

Comment: `print_r($response)` in `getInternalRouteServerResponse()` this method. and now what is you are getting in console?

Comment: or `getInternalRouteServerResponse()` this method run directly in your browser. and let me know

Comment: and you told above your question your ajax request properly working... i am seeing what is problem `getInternalRouteServerResponse()` this method. so you can run directly in browser.

Comment: that's what I get from print_r($response);
Array
(
    [status] => 1
    [journeys] => Array
        (
            [total] => 0
        )

)

Comment: this array result when run directly? or ajax call?

Comment: when I run directy

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/128959/discussion-between-razib-al-mamun-and-miril-terolli).

Comment: i thinks you are not interested solved your problem. I have knock you in discusstion to chat